# How to umount an USB Android device

Tags: android, usb, mount, umount, lsusb

I've connected my Android tablet to Ubuntu in order to write some code using Intellij. Everything works ok, but now I don't know how to disconnect my tablet. My `/media/` and `/mnt/` directories are empty and `lsusb` display this:

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:c062 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0d62:001c Darfon Electronics Corp. Benq X120 Internet Keyboard Pro
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 18d1:0003  <<<---- THE TABLET
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So, how can I safely disconnect my tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output of `mount` and if it is definitely not mounted, just unplug it. There is no problem if no process has access to it.

You may be worried that `lsusb` still display your device, but that is because that command show the usb devices that are *available* - that is, plugged in.

If you have doubts, try to plug a regular flash usb stick, umount it, (with `sudo umount /dev/your_usb_device`) and then do `lsusb` before unplugging it. You'll notice it will still appear there.